# css border style in :before selector not taking full height

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have the below markup, the problem I am facing is with the :before psuedo selector, it isnt occupying all of height of the element it is applied to i.e. as shown in the plunk, the left red border applied in   :before doesn't fully occupies the height. I need it to take the full height. How can I do that, I have been playing with elements height, line-height with text in it, but no luck.

Plunk - http://plnkr.co/edit/NPYntTDHeolsM89vYd2Y?p=preview

HTML:

```
  <body>
    <div>
      <section>

      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
div, section{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
div{
  background:yellow;
  width:200px; 
  height:30px;
}
section{
  background:green; color:white;
  width:50px;
  height:30px; float:right;
}
section:before{
  border-left:5px solid red;
  content:"";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your element has a fixed height, it's simply a matter of setting the height of the pseudo-element to 100%, but you will additionally have to display it as a block because generated content is laid inline by default:

```
section:before{
  border-left:5px solid red;
  content:"";
  display:block;
  height:100%;
}
```